# How to run multiple parallel spark job in AWS EMR clusters through AWS Data Pipe line

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to setup a flow for running spark jobs in EMR clusters using AWS Data PipeLine. And our flow runs on "On Demand" schedule.

As part of this activity, we create an EMR cluster in the begining of the pipe line and then we want to run multiple spark jobs on an emr cluster in parallel.

Is there a we can run parallel jobs on Data Pipe Line with "On Demand" schedule.

Comment: Assign your cluster a "worker group" and have all the Spark activities run there.  If they don't depend on each other, they should start simultaneously.  Then you just maybe have to configure your Spark on YARN (or whatever scheduler) to handle concurrent jobs in the most efficient way for you.

Comment: Thanks, this option worked. Apart from this, is it possible to run a separate activity on failure of my EMRActivity (can be any Activity). I could see only we can send notification. I can handle my notification through lambda and can take care of it. But with in the same pipeline is it possible.

Comment: @user4601931 can you share any further details on how to configure Yarn to handle concurrent jobs

Comment: @Abhi See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html or https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this example
https://github.com/ychantit/airflow_aws_utils
basically you will need to submit your jobs connecting to the emr using ssh and watch the execution of the jobs yourself
but it's not using aws datapipeline...